# SyntaxWalker doesn't visit trivia

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

**Given:**

With a simple syntax walker I want to visit trivias (EndOfLineTrivia to be exact)

```
  public sealed class MyWalker : SyntaxWalker
    {
        public int Lines { get; set; }

        public int Trivia { get; set; }

        public int Node { get; set; }

        public override void Visit(SyntaxNode node)
        {
            Node++;
            base.Visit(node);
        }

        protected override void VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia)
        {
            Trivia++;
            base.VisitTrivia(trivia);
        }
    }
```

I call the Walker like this:

```
    SyntaxTree node = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
    var root = node.GetRoot();
    var walker = new LocWalker();
```

**Problem**

The overriden VisitTrivia Method is never called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is to set the `Depth` of the walker to `SyntaxWalkerDepth.Trivia` (or `SyntaxWalkerDepth.StructuredTrivia`). The default `Depth` is `SyntaxWalkerDepth.Node`, which means that trivia is not visited.

To do that, call the base constructor:

```
public MyWalker() : base(SyntaxWalkerDepth.Trivia)
{
}
```

Comment: Many thanks I didn't realize this constructor overload !